# How does CakePHP rewrite URLs for Plugin CSS

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Just curious how does CakePHP rewrite Urls

.htaccess for cakephp at root is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

which generates normal css links for CakePHP as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cake/css/cake.generic.css" />`

**/cake/css/cake.generic.css**
The path to this file is **C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\app\webroot\css\cake.generic.css** which is achieved by the above .htaccess code.

but, if we add the DebugKit (for example) or any other plugin to cakephp the css files are rewritten as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cake/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css" />`

**/cake/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css**
The path to this file is **C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\app\Plugin\DebugKit\webroot\css\debug_toolbar.css**

I am searching for a *.htaccess* file which does this, but could not find one. What is the way that CakePHP has achieved this or one can achieve this.

Comment: This is most likely not achieved by using htaccess, but rather a router script that detects which plugin the CSS file belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

This is not just htaccess, this uses the AssetDispatcher:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html

This way it essentially routes the assets via CakePHP Dispatcher, which uses PHP and is a little bit more overhead than symlinking the files into webroot directly (as the docs suggest).

Comment: Can you help me with a small example which could achieve similar